# Shortcut Ctrl + B doesn't work inside Component Tree to Go to XML in Android Studio Windows

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

[image: Screen Shot of Component Tree that shows Shortcut Ctrl + B]

Can any of you see working this shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to Go to XML of the selected component from Component Tree in Android Studio?

It doesn't work for me whenever I try even from different computers.

Is there anything to do make it to work or doesn't it work at all?. Though I can see other shortcuts like cut(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>), copy(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>), paste(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) working very fine.

Comment: I've reproduced it in Android Studio 2.3.3 (I use Windows)

Comment: Do you mean you have the same problem or you fixed it?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Okay. Thanks for confirmation

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio 3.0. Bug still alive. So i decided to create bug report:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68674209

Comment: Thank you for your initiative